# search root words in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle.

I have 1 database which stores CLOB datatype in 1 of the column.

How can I search for the string `#include( UTILITIES, 10_MORNING, EVENING )` but exclude occurrences of the string `//#include( UTILITIES, 10_MORNING, EVENING )` from the resultset?

I am using the below command but it returns both strings above:

```
select ID  
from SCRIPTS
where regexp_like(MFG_SCRIPT, '#include( UTILITIES, 10_MORNING, EVENING )') 
order by ID
```

Comment: You seem to have the same values in your include and exclude lists.  Is this correct?

Comment: is not 100% same values. as u can see the different is '//' at the front 1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the comments in the CLOB like the below

```
  select ID  
  from SCRIPTS
  where regexp_like(MFG_SCRIPT, '#include( UTILITIES, 10_MORNING, EVENING )') 
  and not regexp_like (MFG_SCRIPT,'//+')
  order by ID
```

For using % in regexp you have to use escape character for ()

```
 select * from SCRIPTS
 where regexp_like(MFG_SCRIPT, 'include\( UTILITIES, 10_MORNING, EVENING \)')
```

Comment: how to convert % to regex formation as above?
original query is below

..where MFG_SCRIPT like '%include( UTILITIES, 10_MORNING, EVENING )%'